# Change List<Object> into List<List<int>> using LINQ

Tags: arrays, json, list, linq, chart.js

I have an application using the following model:

```
namespace myapp.Models.Types
{
        public class PressureRowT
        {
            public System.DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
            public int P1{ get; set; }
            public int P2{ get; set; }
            public int P3{ get; set; }
            public int P4{ get; set; }
            public int P5{ get; set; }
        }
}
```

I have a List< PressureRowT > with approximately 5000 elements, generated by parsing files. I need to plot the pressure by passing the data to chart.js for data viewing. For that, I would need a JSON array like:

```
[Timestamp: [date1, date2, date3... daten], P1: [val1, val2, val3, ..., valn], P2: [val1, val2, val3, ..., valn] ... P5: [val1, val2, val3, ..., valn]]
```

What would be the most efficient way of "inverting" the structure ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming right now you have a list of PressureRowT and you want an object PressureRowT with lists within it, you can use something like

```
var Timestamps = pressureRowTList.Select(pressureRowT => pressureRowT.TimeStamp).ToList();
```

for each of the fields and assign them all to one object.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to re-write your parsing code to build the correct structures as the files are read.

Barring that, the best thing to do is not use LINQ, but simply build the `List`s needed. A `for` loop is more efficient than a `foreach` when processing a `List`:

```
var src = new List<PressureRowT>();

var srccount = src.Count;
var PR_TS = new List<DateTime>(srccount);
var PR_P1 = new List<int>(srccount);
var PR_P2 = new List<int>(srccount);
var PR_P3 = new List<int>(srccount);
var PR_P4 = new List<int>(srccount);
var PR_P5 = new List<int>(srccount);

for (int j1 = 0; j1 < srccount; ++j1) {
    PR_TS.Add(src[j1].Timestamp);
    PR_P1.Add(src[j1].P1);
    PR_P2.Add(src[j1].P2);
    PR_P3.Add(src[j1].P3);
    PR_P4.Add(src[j1].P4);
    PR_P5.Add(src[j1].P5);
}

var ans = new { Timestamp = PR_TS, P1 = PR_P1, P2 = PR_P2, P3 = PR_P3, P4 = PR_P4, P5 = PR_P5 };
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick reply, I will do that for now. I had a doubt about that too. The structure I need for display and for data processing are unfortunately different ... maybe I should store both structure in DB ?

Comment: @Valentin Or create a class (`PressureRowList`) that stores the data in one format (probably charting format) and provides a view of the data in the other format (e.g. default indexed property for `PressureRowList` returns a new `PressureRowT`), though that may generate extra garbage and storage overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I might use [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) to build up the result object:

```
IEnumerable<PressureRowT> values;
var resultSeed = new {
    Timestamp = new List<DateTime>(),
    P1 = new List<int>(),
    P2 = new List<int>(),
    P3 = new List<int>(),
    P4 = new List<int>(),
    P5 = new List<int>(),
};

return values.Aggregate(
    resultSeed,
    (result, value) => {
        result.Timestamp.Add(value.Timestamp);
        result.P1.Add(value.P1);
        result.P2.Add(value.P2);
        result.P3.Add(value.P3);
        result.P4.Add(value.P4);
        result.P5.Add(value.P5);
        return result;
    });
```

Comment: Nice use of `Aggregate`. Couldn't you put `resultSeed` inline in the call?

Comment: @NetMage, yes, it could be defined inline